# Bipartite graph G(U,V,E) with directed edges from U to V only

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, bipartite-graphs

I wonder if in the graph theory community or in any other subfield there is a name for a bipartite graph $G(U,V,E)$ with the property of having all edges $(i,j)\in E$ such that $i\in U$ and $j\in V$. Basically directed edges go from $U$ to $V$, but not the other way around.

Also, as extra question that does not really need an answer (due to potential overwhelming amount of possible answers), what is the most obvious implication of a graph with such properties and where are they commonly found?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have found thus far.

- Such a graph has no cycles, therefore it is a directed-acyclic-graph.